# Show alert if specific option is selected

Tags: jquery

I have some code that creates a drop-down box, with a bunch of options, and an i don't know option. I am trying to use jQuery to say if idk is selected, alert ("it may take additonal time to route your request");

I am trying to use the .focusout event,  nested inside a conditional statement to trigger the alert. Not even sure I can do that, but that's really the best way to do what I want since I do not want to see the alert for any option that is selected.

Here's a link to my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JustJill54/ye8rG/

Ideally I'd love to be able to say- but i can't. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
$("option[value='idk']").focusout(function(){
    alert("If no organizational element is selected, additional time may be required to route this request");
});
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to listen for events on the `select` element, not the `option`. There were some syntax errors as well. I've [updated your fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XFaaG/).

Note that from a UX perspective, there might be more subtle ways to inform the user than an intrusive alert box popping up in their face. For example, a new span of text could appear, or some other visual indicator that does not disrupt their workflow.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Attach to the focusout event of the select, if that's when
    // you want to check the value
    $("select[title='organizationalElement']").focusout(function(){
        // Now see if it's the value you want
        if ($(this).val() === 'idk'){
            alert("If no organizational element is selected, additional time may be required to route this request");
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: Am new at using fiddle. <br>Actually kind of wanted alert to be intrusive, so that user's can't miss it.<br> Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late but oh well, here's my slightly different answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.org').focusout(function(){
         if($(this).val() == 'idk')
         {
              alert("If no organizational element is selected, additional time may be required to route this request");
         }  
    });
});
```

but my 2 cents to add is this: I don't know why people decide to use elaborate selectors on objects that have specific classes or id's to them. In this case you can select on the class .org and not have to evaluate the title of the element. Better yet, assign an id to it so jquery stops traversing when it hits that element.

Answer (score 1):

I found two issues with your jsfiddle (included here for reference):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($("select[title='organizationalElement']").val() == "idk') {
    $(this).focusout(function(){
      alert("If no organizational element is selected, additional time may be required to route this request");
    });
  });
});
```

1. Syntax errors
2. You were running the conditional before binding to the event, rather than inside of the event itself

Here's an over-simplified working example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').focusout(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'idk') {
      alert('Some message');
    }
  });
});
```

This differs from yours in two key ways:

1. Note that you're trying to close an `if` block with `});` instead of just `}`.  Probably just a typo.  There were also some mis-matched single- and double-quotes.
2. The event binding is the first concern, the conditional is the second concern.  In your version, you're basically saying: "When the page first loads, if the value of the `select` is `idk` then bind this event to it, which will show an alert."  Note the difference.  The value will never be `idk` when the page first loads, and that code will never be executed again.  Instead, bind the event to always fire when the element loses focus and check the conditional inside the event.